# Redirect user to another (custom) aspx page if he click on My Settings option in Sharepoint

Tags: redirect

I would like to redirect user to another (custom) aspx page if he click on My Settings option in SharePoint. Is it possible to redirect to another page and not to default one?

Comment: My settings or site settings?

Comment: It is "My settings"

Answer (score 0):

You may well try attaching a click event to the class. Something like

```
$('.ms-siteactions-root').click()
```